# nodejs jasmine test fails on 'expect' | 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'expect(true).toBe(true)')

Tags: node.js, grunt-contrib-jasmine

I have setup a simple spec:

```
describe("A suite", function() {
  it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

And when I run `grunt jasmine` I get:

```
Running "jasmine:src" (jasmine) task
Testing jasmine specs via PhantomJS

 A suite
   × contains spec with an expectation
     TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'expect(true).toBe(tru
e)') in file:///C:/Users/long-path-to-spec/testing-spec.js (line 4) (1)


1 spec in 0s.
>> 1 failures
Warning: Task "jasmine:src" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

It seems to be running the spec... it seems to know what 'describe' and 'it' are, but it seems to be unaware of 'expect'?

Any ideas?